# Filter options in 'Selenium Page Object Generator' (Chrome Plugin)

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, google-chrome-devtools, pageobjects

I need to generate a Page Object Model for a page to use with Selenium WebDriver. My page is so complex that the 'Selenium Page Object Generator' plugin generates 5000 lines of code from the code body without any filter.

[image: Options in 'Selenium Page Object Generator' plugin]

**My Requirement**: I need to filter and retrieve only the page objects from the code block under HTML id = "xyz" (example).

**My Question**: What should be the filter criteria under 'Root Selector' in the above options window? Or is there any other options that I must try.

***Note:*** I am raising this question due to the lack of information/guidelines available to use this plugin. Any informative links are also appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding (body) in the root selector text-box

After trying the plugin for a little bit I don't think the root selector accepts operators like (=)

What you can do is to narrow your criteria a little bit

Example :
You need to get all the web elements under a certain table

You can add (table,tbody,td) in the root selector and the tool will get all the Elements under all the tables in your page having below hierarchy :

```
<table>
  <tbody>
     <td>
      Element1
      Element2
      Element3
     </td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The default value for 'Root Selector' was 'body' and that is the problem. I want the root selector to be set to a block of HTML code only under body. For example a table with id = "xyz".

Comment: I gave a try as you mentioned but no WebElements were captured. And also there were too many html tables available but I need to fetch only one of them.